# Copy multiple columns with formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a google script function that creates a new day.
What I want is to copy the content of the columns **BO** to **CA** next to the last empty column, as shown in the image.

[image]

In the script I have this code:

```
var columnsPerDay = 13;
var sheetName = 'Principal';
function NuevoDia() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var lastDayColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastDayRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastDayRange = sheet.getRange(1, lastDayColumn, sheet.getMaxRows(), columnsPerDay);
  var nextDayRange = sheet.getRange(1, lastDayColumn + 1, sheet.getMaxRows());
  lastDayRange.activate();

//  var lastDayRangeValues = lastDayRange.getValues();
  //lastDayRange.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, lastDayColumn + 13, sheet.getMaxRows()))

  //lastDayRange.activate();
/*
  var lastDayRangeValues = lastDayRange.getValues();
  nextDayRange.setValues(lastDayRangeValues);
*/ 
 lastDayRange.copyValuesToRange(sheet, lastDayRange.getLastColumn()+1, lastDayRange.getLastColumn()+columnsPerDay, 13, lastDayRange.getLastRow())
};
```

As you can see I have lot's of comments in the code with different failed attempts...

Comment: What is the failure?  Have you debugged?  Logs?

Comment: The failure is that is not coping the complete columns (only the last one).

Comment: That's because your range is mis-referenced.  `getRange(start row, start col, # rows, # cols)`.  Your range:  Start row = 1, start col = last col, # rows = total rows, # cols = 13.  Since you are doing a static 13 columns every time, you could use multiples of 13, or just copy from the first 13 (start col = 1) every time.

Comment: Can you explain it with functional code in an answer, so I can mark it as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy range is mis-referenced. `getRange(start row, start col, # rows, # cols)`. Your range: Start row = 1, start col = last col, # rows = total rows, # cols = 13.  This is why only the last column is copied.

Change:

```
var lastDayRange = sheet.getRange(1, lastDayColumn, sheet.getMaxRows(), columnsPerDay);
```

to:

```
var lastDayRange = sheet.getRange(1, lastDayColumn - 12, sheet.getMaxRows(), columnsPerDay);
```

(I changed the `lastDayColumn` implementation from my comment after I looked at your picture again and realized you would not necessarily be working from the origin.)

I think you could also simplify the copy step.  From:

```
lastDayRange.copyValuesToRange(sheet, lastDayRange.getLastColumn()+1, lastDayRange.getLastColumn()+columnsPerDay, 13, lastDayRange.getLastRow())
```

to:

```
lastDayRange.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, lastDayColumn +1));
```

(Unless you are trying to paste multiple days at once, then `copyValuesToRange()` is likely better, but your implementation could be cleaned up)

```
lastDayRange.copyValuesToRange(sheet, lastDayColumn +1, lastDayColumn +columnsPerDay, 1, lastDayRange.getLastRow())
```

Let me know if there are any problems with any of this.